# Pandas: counting unique combinations from four columns that have NaN values

Tags: pandas

I've been scratching my head with the this.. I have a dataframe with four columns

```
   a   b    c    d

0  1   1   Nan  NaN
1  2   1    1   NaN
2  1   1   Nan  NaN
3  3   2    1    3
```

and I want the count of unique combinations from the columns to a new column

```
   a   b    c    d    count

0  1   1   Nan  NaN     2
1  2   1    1   NaN     1
3  3   2    1    3      1
```

I've been using:

```
df.groupby(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).size().reset_index().rename(columns={0:'count'})
```

but this only gives me rows where every column has a value that is not Nan:

```
   a   b    c    d    count

0  3   2    1    3      1
```

How can I get all combinations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to go around is to replace `NaN` values with the string `'NaN'`:

```
(df.fillna('NaN')
   .groupby(list(df.columns))['a'].size()
   .reset_index(name='count')
)
```

Output:

```
   a  b    c    d  count
0  1  1  NaN  NaN      2
1  2  1    1  NaN      1
2  3  2    1    3      1
```